# Python - Can't import with_statement from __future__

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import, with-statement

Here are the other imports already in my app

```
import os
import sys
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

import cgi
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

from django.utils import simplejson as json
from datetime import datetime

import random
import string

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

from google.appengine.api import files
```

Everything compiles and works fine.

But when I add this import:

`from __future__ import with_statement`

nothing works. I go to appspot, and the page just says "server error."

How can I successfully import `with_satement`?

EDIT:

I I know `blobstore` is deprecated. `with` is used with `blobstore`. Could that be what's causing the problem? But `with` isn't *only* used with `blobstore`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the import to the very top of your file (after any `#!/usr/bin/python2.x` statements).

Answer (score 4):

from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file